# Text Background color size

Tags: image, text, colors, background, hover

I'm wondering if I can change the background's size of the text.

I mean, I have a navbar who contain an image with text over `<ul><li>` then
I added a `display:flex;` property.

All the links are separated by little bars.

When I mouse over the links, I change the background color or image with hover. However, the background doesn't fill the area between the little bars.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
nav li {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
nav a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #666060;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li .news:hover {
  background: url("Images/news.png");
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <img src="Images/NavBar.png" alt="NavBar" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="Images/Home.png" alt="Home" title="home" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="news"> News </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat"> Chat </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="forum"> Forum </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="contact"> Contact </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Because you did not include the image link for us to test, I cannot see what is wrong. However, you can use `background-size` property to set the size of the image. it's syntax is `background-size:WIDTHpx HEIGHTpx

Comment: Basically, even if I replace background: url by background-color I have the same issue.